# volatile __thread, pointless?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, volatile

There are some examples on the Internet of people declaring their variables both `volatile` and `__thread`. I think it's a mistake because `__thread` implies that there's a copy for each thread, so with `volatile` the "best" you can do is disable caching of such variable, for some obscure reasons. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two terms are not mutually exclusive. `volatile` is not only used in matters of multi-threading, it's used for any situation the variable might change without the current code block being aware -- such as callback functions, or signal handlers.

Comment: Also, I don't think there's anything to stop you passing a pointer to a thread-local variable to another thread, in which case *volatile* would be appropriate.